# Python regex explanation needed - $ character usage

Tags: python, regex

My apologies for a completely newbie question. I did try searching stackoverflow first before posting this question.

I am trying to learn regex using python from diveintopython3.net. While fiddling with the examples, I failed to understand one particular output
for a regex search (shown below):

```
>>> pattern = 'M?M?M?$'

>>> re.search(pattern,'MMMMmmmmm')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f0aa8095168>
```

Why does the above regex pattern match the input text? My understanding is that the $ character should match only at the end of the string. But the input text ends with `'mmmm'`. So i though the patterns should not match.

My python version is :

```
Python 3.3.2 (default, Dec  4 2014, 12:49:00)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)] on linux
```

EDIT: Attached a screenshot from Debuggex.[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does the above regex pattern match the input text?

Because you made the previous `M`'s as optional. `M?` refers an optional `M`. `M` may or maynot present. So the above regex `'M?M?M?$'` matches only the zero width end of the line boundary. Hence you got a match.

Answer (score 3):

It is because all the `M` symbols are optional, and `$` (the only required symbol in this regex) matches at the end. You have a regex that is equal to [zero-length assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), that captures no characters but still there are matches.

Here is a visualization:

```
M?M?M?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DkYUHdSrGUCDdGyP)

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev. The Debuggex Demo for the same pattern and input text shows "Does not match" for python. I have attached a screenshot of the same in the original post. Could you help me in understanding why this is happening?

Comment: You can move the slider to any position to check if the match appears at that very location. Since the match is at the end, the triangle at the beginning of a string shows no match. It is just for debugging, to show more match internals.